# What facilitates a fair representation of women in government in Rwanda?

Tags: gender, rwanda

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_government

What facilitates a fair representation of women in government in Rwanda? According to Wikipedia, Rwanda has one of the highest representation of women in government with 61.25% in the lower house and 38.46% in the higher house. What facilitate this fair representation or makes it possible to have such a good representation of women within their government. I would like to know what are the political reasons such as law, hiring procedure, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest answer is that Rwanda legally requires women to be represented in government.  [Their consitution](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Rwanda_2015) stipulates that:

> At least thirty percent (30%) of Deputies must be women.

> At least thirty percent (30%) of elected and appointed Senators must be women.

This is made possible by a [closed party list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_list) election system, in which each party is required to have at least 30% women on their list of nominees.  This contrasts with [open list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_list) or [primary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_election)-based nomination systems, in which party nominees are chosen by ordinary voters who are not obligated to meet gender quotas.

As for cultural reasons, [you can largely “thank” the 1994 genocide](https://www.npr.org/sections/goatsandsoda/2016/07/29/487360094/invisibilia-no-one-thought-this-all-womans-debate-team-could-crush-it).  With a huge number of men having died or fled the country, Rwanda's remaining population was 60-70% female.  Women's influence in society was thus increased due to sheer numbers.